# I am unable to implement react-routing in my project

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-routing, react-link

```
function Nav() {
    return (
        <>
            <BrowserRouter>
                <Routes>
                    <Route path="/" element={<Homepage />} />
                    <Route path="/bookingpage" element={<BookingPage />} />
                </Routes>
            </BrowserRouter>

            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <img src="" alt="logo" />

                    <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
                    <li><Link to="/about">About</Link></li>
                    <li><Link to="/menu">Menu</Link></li>
                    <li><Link to="/bookingpage">Reservations</Link></li>
                    <li><Link to="/order">Order Online</Link></li>
                    <li><Link to="/login">Login</Link></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>


        </>
    );
}
```

error here is:

```
Cannot destructure property 'basename' of 'react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.useContext(...)' as it is null.
TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'basename' of 'react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.useContext(...)' as it is null.
```